# Eclipse 32 bit crash linux

Tags: eclipse

When i start eclipse(32) in linux (eclipse 64 start correctly )- I see this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
    /usr/bin/java
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -jar /home/devil/bin/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    -os linux
    -ws gtk
    -arch x86
    -showsplash /home/devil/bin/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800/splash.bmp
    -launcher /home/devil/bin/eclipse/eclipse
    -name Eclipse
    --launcher.library /home/devil/bin/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
    -startup /home/devil/bin/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    --launcher.overrideVmargs
    -exitdata 6d8006
    -vm /usr/bin/java
    -vmargs
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -jar /home/devil/bin/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

what does it mean? Help me please

version java - 6 uname :

```
linux devil-desktop 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

java version :

```
java version "1.6.0_38" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05) Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: could you give us a little bit more info on your system by showing us the output of "uname -a" and "java -version" ?? I would also suggest to switch to oracle's/suns's sdk 6 or 7

Comment: version java - 6 uname : inux devil-desktop 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version : java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem. Though solved it by switching from OpenJDK to SunJDK. Hope it works for you also

Answer (score 0):

ok you are most likely running a 64bit version of java on your mashine.
Your 32-bit version of eclipse refuses to start because it needs to run on a 32-bit version of java.

What you will need to do is get a 32-bit version of java, extract it and tell eclipse where to find it.
Here is a guide I found which describes this procedure in more detail:
http://rachaelandtom.info/node/1485